# Determining the co-presenters of a conference presentation when the work is already published

Tags: conference, authorship, presentation

I am the lead author of an article publication, and there are 3 co-authors for this publication.

I will submit a proposal to a major conference to present the findings of this published work, and I will be the only one who will do the presentation.

So, I wonder if I should indicate only my name for the submission, or should I also include the co-author's name also as the co-presenter although they will literally no present anything.

I know it is not nice to exclude them since they contributed to the study, and I will probably include their names. However, I want to know what is common practice for this.

Comment: Of course they are co-authors. Look at the abstract book of any conference - almost all abstracts have multiple authors, but only one will present. One exception might be invited/plenary talks, where it is expected that the talk will cover a broad area of the author's work, and collaborators names will be indicated in the different appropriate sections.

Comment: I'd also add that these three people should know of your proposal. It's a common courtesy to circulate the proposal among them. They can give comments if necessary. Also, in case if it's accepted they may want to add that to their resume/CV. So please inform them now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common practice is to include all the authors of the publication/research that the presentation is based on, regardless of which authors attend the conference.  When in doubt, always include all authors.

If you're the only one attending the conference, list yourself as lead/contact author.  That's the only difference.